# How Horoscopes (Jataka) are written?

Tags: belief, scripture, tradition, astrology

How do astrologers writes a Horoscope of new born child? Can they be accurate in determining one's life partner or destiny?

Comment: When Einstein gave the General Theory of Relativity, it is said that only 8 people in the world understood what he was saying. I believe the same goes here, astrology is a science but the number of good astrologers can be counted on your fingertips.

Answer (score 3):

The astrological charts of a new-born baby are written taking the moment when the child takes its first breath (independent of its mother). The planetary positions at that moment determine the pre-destined portion of the child's life (prarabdha Karma that the child brings from its previous incarnations/births). Hence, the Natal horoscope (Jataka) will greatly shape the proceedings of the individual's course of life and will play a predominant role in influencing its will, determining the circumstances that the he/she will face and conditioning the abilities at different ages.

Having said that, the individual can use its free will to counteract the influences and, by virtue of blessing from higher souls, the individual can endure (and in certain occasions, overcome) the pre-destined fate.

Answering your second question, there is a curse on astrology that no human can have a accurate (100%) prediction on all aspects such as what, why, how, where, when and by whom (at the same time). However, with reasonable accuracy and precision, destiny can be deciphered (with decently accurately but limited precision). Life partner being a subset of destiny can also be predicted. Most predictions will be indicative and significantly reliable given that the astrologer is well learnt, the dashas and antardashas of the astrologer is reasonably favorable, has yogas that made him an astrologer with Vak Siddhi (capable of saying things that come true) and the querist has the bhagya to know the truth at that juncture of time.

Though all this looks complex by analysis, it is an experiential learning that will help have a better understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Answers on this site should be supported with reliable sources. Can you cite sources for statements ." Charts are written for time of first breath" and " Curse on Astrology"?

Comment: So, according to Science, Babies will air take for the first time when they cry. So, "should we use time when babies cry for the first time" for Astrological Charts?

Comment: @The destroyer:
Unfortunately i do not have a clear citation to your first question on source of the curse. If you are familiar with Mahabharatha, this example will be of some help.

Comment: Sahadeva was a very great astrologer who is also a student of Deva Guru Brihaspati himself. He could predict outcomes of the kurukshetra war much before hand and was capable enough to also prescribe muhurtas that could make Kauravas win. But, the curse has to play its role to make prarabdha karma come true.

Comment: With respect to your second question, the time the child takes its first breath is to be taken. Now whether the child cries, is on oxygen mask and breathing or anything else is left to the circumstance at birth. Under normal conditions, the instant it starts crying is to be taken.